Running a script in a virtualized environment, capturing output and abstacting keyboard and mouse inputs from main system
I have an autonomous software development system, which is able to generate and iteratively develop an application.
The agent has the ability to run terminal commands like any other developer. for example the ai can run: python chess.py and have it run on my system.
So let's say my AI was able to develop a chess game. The AI will then need to test if his implementation of the chess game is correct or not. Therefore he will create a file called test.py.
test.py will:

Initialize the Chess Application
Issue Keyboard and Mouse Inputs in order to autonomously control the application and for example, test out if the pawn chess piece can move

the way that I had done that is using this function:
def execute_shell_command(command, TIMEOUT_SECONDS=5, stdin="", stream=False):
original_directory = os.getcwd()
output_file = os.path.join(original_directory, 'vision', 'stream_terminal_output.mp4')
venv_name = find_venv_name(Path("playground"))
stdout, stderr, returncode = None, None, None
stop_capture = threading.Event()
video_ready = threading.Event()
process_info = ProcessInfo()
capture_thread = None
video_generated = False

if stream:
    capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=capture_loop, args=(stop_capture, video_ready, output_file, process_info))
    capture_thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.65)

try:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(original_directory, "playground"))
    if venv_name:
        scripts_dir = Path(venv_name) / ("Scripts" if os.name == "nt" else "bin")
        venv_activation_path = scripts_dir / ("activate.bat" if os.name == "nt" else "activate")
        full_command = f'cmd /c "{venv_activation_path} & {command}"' if os.name == "nt" else f"source {venv_activation_path} && {command}"
    else:
        full_command = command

    start_time = time.time()
    process = subprocess.Popen(full_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE if stdin else None)
    
    process_info.pid = process.pid
    process_info.ready.set()

    timeout = 120 if any(keyword in command for keyword in ['venv', 'pip', 'install', 'download', 'update', 'upgrade', 'git clone', 'npm', 'yarn', 'build', 'compile', 'make']) else TIMEOUT_SECONDS

    try:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=stdin, timeout=timeout)
        output = stdout.strip()
        error = stderr.strip()
        returncode = process.returncode
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        window = find_window_for_process(process.pid)
        if window:
            try:
                if stream:
                    stop_capture.set()
                window.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error closing window: {str(e)}")

        for _ in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if process.poll() is not None:
                break

        if process.poll() is None:
            terminate_process_tree(process.pid)

        process.kill()
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        output = stdout.strip()
        error = stderr.strip()
        returncode = process.returncode
        if returncode == 15:
            execution_time = time.time() - start_time
            error = f"The system terminated the process due to Timeout. Total execution time: {execution_time:.2f}s with Timeout set to: {timeout}s. Please change your implementation to fit in the selected Timeout: {timeout}s. This error could also have happened because of an infinite loop." + error

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.stdout.strip() if e.stdout else ""
    error = e.stderr.strip() if e.stderr else ""
    returncode =  e.returncode
except Exception as e:
    output = ""
    error = str(e)
    returncode = 1
finally:
    if stream and capture_thread:
        stop_capture.set()
        capture_thread.join(timeout=5)
        video_generated = video_ready.wait(timeout=10)
    os.chdir(original_directory)

return output, error, returncode, venv_name, video_generated

But then there are problems to this approach, which are:

If the AI misclicked, the window will go out of focus. The rest of his Inputs will still apply though.
The screen capture mechanism will face some issues, because the ai autonomously clicked away from the application. Making the Screen Capture freeze up. And not show the result of his inputs

Now, is it possible to make the test script run in a virtualized environment instead?

This means that the Keyboard and Mouse Inputs will only affect the application run by the command
The Screen Capture should no longer capture the entire screen. it should instead directly capture whatever visual output the application is presenting. Currently, Application displays visual content on my windows screen. Then with mss i capture that application window. But this is suboptimal, as the window can get out of focus. I want to directly capture the visual output of the application.
I have already experimented with keeping the application window in focus the whole time. But this sadly produces more errors that i don't even understand.

So how can I do this? I would appreciate any help offered or any advice!
test.py would look like this:
import pygame
import sys
from chessboard import Chessboard
from autonomous_control_helper import get_board_state, get_piece_at_position, move_piece, is_valid_move
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
import time


def test_pawn_movement():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Chess Game - Pawn Movement Test")

    chessboard = Chessboard()
    mouse = MouseController()
    keyboard = KeyboardController()

    chessboard.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    print("0.0s: Initial board setup displayed")

    # Test white pawn movement
    start_positions = [(0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6)]
    end_positions = [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4)]

    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(start_positions, end_positions)):
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second between moves

        # Convert board coordinates to screen coordinates
        start_x, start_y = start[0] * 100 + 50, start[1] * 100 + 50
        end_x, end_y = end[0] * 100 + 50, end[1] * 100 + 50

        # Move mouse to start position and click
        mouse.position = (start_x, start_y)
        mouse.click(Button.left)

        # Move mouse to end position and click
        mouse.position = (end_x, end_y)
        mouse.click(Button.left)

        # Update the board
        if is_valid_move(chessboard, start, end):
            move_piece(chessboard, start, end)
            chessboard.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            print(f"{i+1}.0s: Moved pawn from {start} to {end}")
        else:
            print(f"{i+1}.0s: Invalid move from {start} to {end}")

    # Keep the window open for 5 seconds
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 5:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_pawn_movement()

The new execute shell command should be universal and work on any application and not just PyGame
